Can the Sidecar API be used to replace the excludeInboundPorts annotation?
I'm trying to add a port exclusion to the Istio proxy sidecar configuration, without having to resort to the annotation
traffic.sidecar.istio.io/excludeInboundPorts: "xxxx"


Is this possible via the Sidecar API?
The reason being is that the Helm chart we're using to deploy something doesn't have hooks to add it through a Helm value override, and we don't own the chart.  We'd like to avoid making our own copy of it and modifying it if possible.
From other things I've read you should be able to define
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Sidecar
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
  ingress:
  - port:
   ....
  egress:
    - hosts:
      - "./*"
      - "istio-system/*"
  outboundTrafficPolicy:
    mode: ALLOW_ANY

and anything not declared in the ingress ports section would be excluded from the mesh.  However we're in STRICT mode so maybe the behavior's different.
